# Can vstest.console.exe return the number of tests before running?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Is there a way that I can get the number of unit tests that meet the TestFilterCase before executing the tests themselves?

For example if I set a TestCategory of "debug", can I get the number of tests with that tag? Or even more specifically, can I get the number of tests that are not tagged at all?

Comment: build your solution and you can see the number in test explorer window

Comment: My question was more about getting that info from cmd

Comment: `/ListTests` or `/ListDiscoverers`